# cmake cannot include custom module

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to include my custom cmake module.
My folder hierarchy is like so:

```
- project
  - cmake
    - add_FetchContent_MakeAvailable.cmake
  - CMakeLists.txt
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)
project(proj
    VERSION 1.0.0
    LANGUAGES CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

include(FetchContent)
if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.14)
   include(add_FetchContent_MakeAvailable)
endif()
```

But I get the following error:

```
  include could not find load file:
    add_FetchContent_MakeAvailable
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you **actually** have the file `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/add_FetchContent_MakeAvailable.cmake`, the code should work. You may output this path via `message()` command, then run `cmake` again and copy the absolute file path from the `cmake` output. After that, run `ls <copied-absolute-file-path>`.

Comment: Yea I actually have it there, but I can't run `cmake` since it fails on this line when `include` is called so if I set a result variable to path I cant print it with `message`

Comment: Place `message(STATUS  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/add_FetchContent_MakeAvailable.cmake")` **before** the `include()` line. So `cmake` will print the path even if it fails then.

Comment: It just print the absolute path of the module which is correct, don't know how to proceed next since it's seems fine

Comment: "It just print the absolute path of the module which is correct" - Have you checked this path by **copy-pasting** it, e.g. into `ls` command, as I have described in my first comment?

Comment: I have checked your code - it works for me, as expected.

Comment: Well yea I've tried (`dir` since I'm on windows) copy pasting path and the file is there, anything else that can be ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214978/discussion-between-jorayen-and-tsyvarev).